# Is there another expression similar to "the big thing I have going for me"?

Tags: idiom-request

I am not sure if I understand the expression, but I think "the big thing I have going for me" means "my biggest asset is", but I was wondering if there were any other similar expressions, because I can't find synonyms for expressions like that somehow, there's no dictionary for synonymous idioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The big thing I have going for me* is perfectly idiomatic.

However, here are some alternatives in the same general vein:

> My greatest strength.
>   My biggest weapon.
>   My ace in the hole.
>   My secret advantage.
>   My hidden talent.
>   My superpower.

Which you used would depend on exactly what you want to express and how informal you want to sound.

Answer (score -2):

You’re right; “the thing I have going for me” means “my asset”- not sure if I would use “big”. With no adjective, the expression works; “*the* thing” means essentially “*the best* thing” (or “*the only* thing,” depending on context). See examples of usage here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+going+for

As for synonyms- “something I have going for me” is like “my advantage” (or “asset”, as you said)- there are many synonyms listed here: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/advantage